# Are there any languages that let you specify that a function can only be called from a single call site?

Tags: programming-languages, languages

Out of curiosity, are there any languages that let you tag a function with an attribute that indicates that it may only be called from a single call-site, such that if any code tries to call the function from a second call site, the second call-site is flagged as a compile-time error?

For example (pseudocode):

```
unique_call_site void myFunction(int a, int b, int c) {...}

[...]

myFunction(1, 2, 3);  // ok
myFunction(1, 2, 3);  // error -- second call site not allowed!
```

Motivation for the question:  it's sometimes desirable to break functionality out of a function and into its own separate sub-function (if only to keep the original function from getting too large and complicated), but once you do that, then anyone examining the sub-function now has to consider all the different calling-contexts that the sub-function might possibly be called from, and that consideration re-introduces a bit of complexity.  Having the sub-function tagged with a keyword that indicates that it can be called from only a single context (and having the compiler enforce that property) would allow the reader to know right away that they only need to consider that single calling-context when studying how the sub-function might be used.

Comment: Would you not be calling that function several times from test code? If its complex enough to break off, then its complex enough to warrant individually unit testing it.

Comment: FWIW, C++ classes have a "friend" mechanism, and C# an "InternalsVisibleTo", which work both at the granularity of classes, not functions (but these can be utilized to accomplish what you are asking for). However, [list-of-things questions are not welcome here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed) .

Comment: Javascript Function.caller (non-standard) would let you get close to what you describe. It would be a run-time error, not compile time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller I don't think it's a practical answer and would NOT recommend using it.

Comment: to avoid closing this question as beeing to broad: can you add a specific language so we can discuss here how this language handles this?

Comment: I'm not recommending this, but I reckon you could get what you want in any language by abusing a "literate programming" tool.

Comment: Putting the "private" functions in their own C source file with their single user and declaring them "static" would be fairly effective.   Or at an assembly language level one could simply validate the return address and redirect to some exception handler code if it is unauthorized.  These can of course be defeated by modifying the source code, but that's true with just about any mechanism - if you edit it out, it's gone.

Comment: Rust has this in the [std::ops::FnOnce](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) trait

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I am aware of, but many languages allow something like this:

```
void SomeFunction() {
  void InnerFunction(int a, int b, int c) {
    // do stuff!
  }

  // blah blah
  InnerFunction(1,2,3);
}

// some other context
InnerFunction(1,2,3); // error!
```

Which allows you to limit the scope of your sub-functions to the single place they're used.

I personally don't care for this syntax since it hinders testability, adds complexity to the language (parser, name resolution, tooling to name a few), and doesn't provide a whole lot of readability benefit over a more general feature (like simple private functions). If you need to know how often something is used, something like [CodeLens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2017) does that better without modifying the language. YMMV.

Comment: A different way to achieve that, also supported in many languages, is storing a lambda and calling it a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

Many OO languages support `private` methods/functions, that are located within a class, and can only be called from within that class.
You can simply make a small class that conatins only your private method and the method that is allowed to call it.

Comment: This does not do what the question asks for. The 'unique' method could still be called multiple times by the containing small class.

Comment: @Graham - if the class cannot be extended, then only if someone edits the class to do so.  At which point they could also just delete whatever protection specifier was being used, make the private function public, etc...